# Why is animation not working in a List but is working in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

The progress bar animates in a `VStack` but not in the `List`.  Any idea why?

```
import SwiftUI

struct NoAmimationDemo: View {
    
    @State var progress: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button() {
                withAnimation {
                    progress += 20.0
                }
            } label: { Text("Update") }
            
            // ✅ Animating 
            ProgressView("", value: progress, total: 100.0)

            List {
                // ❌ Not animating 
                ProgressView("", value: progress, total: 100.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug, and that the intended behaviour is it *should* work as is. After all, if you change the progress view animation to something else, like:

```
Text("Rotation")
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: progress))
```

Then both `Text`s animate correctly.

You can also do

```
ProgressView("", value: progress, total: 100.0)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: progress))
```

to see the progress bar rotation being animated, but the "progression" is not animated. Ironic!

That said, for some reason, you *can* fix this by just adding a `.transaction` modifier to the non-working progress bar - you don't even have to do anything in the closure.

```
ProgressView("", value: progress, total: 100.0)
    .transaction { _ in }
```

Even something totally unrelated, like `.badge`, fixes it:

```
ProgressView("", value: progress, total: 100.0)
    .badge(0) // the number doesn't seem to matter
```

It seems like there is a specific set of modifiers that fixes this behaviour. My speculation is that the modifiers in this set all do some specific thing to the `ProgressView` in their implementation, and that's what makes the progress view "realise" that the current `Transaction` is animated.

For now I would just stick a `.transaction { _ in }` at the end, since it doesn't do anything in particular, other than fixing this :)